# Download files from Onedrive on WP8

Tags: onedrive

Is it possible to download files from Onedrive to the internal storage of your Windows Phone rather than storing on SD card?

Comment: If you are trying to save something in particular, adding a bit more detail might help someone try to assist you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install an app to handle it for each type of file that you want to be able to use. That app also has to handle the saving of them.

An app can handle many types of files, or just one. But the browser cannot inherently save any arbitrary file to a global storage area.